# Как добавить свое приложение в список Открыть с помощью?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, manifest

Пробую добавить свое приложение в список "Открыть с помощью" для картинок на Андроид 10.
Сделал фильтр для Activity

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

но в список все равно не добавляется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как правильно добавить свое приложение в этот список?

Comment: По-моему атрибуты `android:host` и `android:scheme` здесь лишние. Без них будут открываться все изображения со схемой `content://` и `file://` - если вас это не устраивает, тогда вы должны явно указать все интересующие схемы (`*` не катит)

Comment: спасибо сработало, как обозначить ваш ответ как правильный?